# cannot access OnConfigurationChangedProvider

Tags: java, android

> I encountered an error while running my project, the project is easily built but it doesn't lunch and it has the following error, I just want my project to run.

```
G:\sabkino-master\app\src\main\java\com\sabkino\academy_school\AcademyActivity.java:49: error: cannot access OnConfigurationChangedProvider
public class AcademyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ^
  class file for androidx.core.content.OnConfigurationChangedProvider not found
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue

**class file for androidx.core.content.OnConfigurationChangedProvider not found**

Tried below and issue was fixed :

```
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core:1.8.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change it in the build file.gradle the implementation string 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'